# Error: package or namespace load failed for BRugs

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I'm a Mac OS user who's trying to run BRugs on Windows (BRugs isn't [available for Mac](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BRugs/index.html)). However I'm unable to install the BRugs package. Example:

```
> library(BRugs)

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'BRugs', details:
call: if (!is.na(ob$version)) msg <- paste(msg, "version", ob$version) else msg <- paste(msg, 
error: argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘BRugs’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
2: In findOpenBUGS() : OpenBUGS 3.2.2 or greater must be installed
(if so, this indicates missing registry keys of OpenBUGS).
Setting the environment variable 'OpenBUGS_PATH' in advance of loading 'BRugs' overwrites the path.
See ?loadOpenBUGS in order to load OpenBUGS manually.
3: In is.na(ob$version) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘BRugs’
```

I've also tried to reinstall BRugs, but the error persists:

```
> remove.packages("BRugs")
> install.packages("BRugs", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: the message says you need to install Openbugs first  `In findOpenBUGS() : OpenBUGS 3.2.2 or greater must be installed` first

Answer (score 0):

I read in a book that "if you're using MacOS, you need to run the windows version of R within WINE".
then go to the following website and there are some more instructions about the packages. http://www.openbugs.net/w/Downloads

Comment: Can you clarify please, why does it need `WINE`?